# Pushdown automata to Context free: how to do it?

Tags: context-free-grammar, pushdown-automaton

I need to write the CFG that generate to the following automata.

I know that a transition like this:

```
-es, es; S lead to a rule like S-> es
-es, B; es lead to a rule like B -> es
-es, B; aB lead to a rule like B-> aB
```

es stands for empty string.

But I have don't know how to deal with rules like "c, a; a". Anyone can give me any help? Thank you.

http://tonguim.free.fr/divers/automata.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, each production is a finite state machine that shows the parser's progress through that production.

The stack used by the automaton is a stack of such production states.  Every time you descend into a production, you push on its initial state.  Every time you conclude one, you pop its now-final state off.  Terminals can be viewed as degenerate productions whose state machines have a single state.

Comment: Thanks @phs for your answer. Please can you give an example because your explanation didn't help me much? Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#PDA_and_Context-free_Languages says it well.  The rest of the page has some examples also.